# Jupyterlab giving warnings in --collaborative mode and not opening notebooks

Tags: server, jupyter-lab, collaboration

I'm trying to run

```
jupyter lab --collaborative
```

It starts correctly but as soon as I connect to the server (open the url in my browser), I start getting warnings of this kind

```
[W 2023-03-03 13:41:26.430 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/yjs/JupyterLab:globalAwareness (f27a4ba663914e8e9a843d5164dba561@127.0.0.1) 2.88ms referer=None
```

and I can't open or create any notebook (it gets stuck loading forever)

I tried starting jupyterlab without the --collaborative option adn everything worked fine.
Can someone explain to me what is happening? (I am nowhere close to an expert on anything computer related, so I would greatly appreciate an easy to understand answer)